# find favorite products of a specific user mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a User collection with an array of favorite products

```
User {
  favoriteProducts: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

now I have query that fetch 10 products at a time so how can I check which one of these products are in user favoriteProducts list. there must be a way with aggregation framework and $setIntersection

the output must be some thing like this

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: "productA",
        isFavorite: false,
    },
    {
        _id: 2,
        name: "productB",
        isFavorite: true,
    },
    {
        _id: 3,
        name: "productC",
        isFavorite: true,
    },
    {
        _id: 4,
        name: "productD",
        isFavorite: false,
    },
]
```

Comment: What is the relation between `User` collection & products ? Also what is your input to query & on which collection are you executing it ?

Comment: the Id of products are store in user favoriteProducts array

Comment: So you mean to say products can be favorite to any user ? You're not looking for specific users ? Also is `favoriteProducts` is an array of `ObjectId()`'s ?

Comment: every user with id x have an array of favorite products
I have a query that fetch 10 products on every step I want to know if these fetched products are in user wish list or not